# How to trigger event when dragged text on a div or dropped a text on a div

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, dom-events

Imagine I have a text which selected from another window, and dragged over a div when I dropped the text on the div, I want to trigger an event and capture the dropped text. I know its working on a text box. But I can't find the event triggering.

```
<div onTextDropped="handleTextDrop()">

</div>
```

I want to implement something like above and I want to GET the dropped TEXT

```js
function dropped(){

  console.log('dropped')

}
```

```html
<div ondrop="dropped()" onClick="clicked()" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red">
  drop text here
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think ondrop event may satisfy you
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

```
function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The p element was dropped";
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_ondrop

to log selected text

```
function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  console.log(data)

}
```

Comment: but how you get the value of dragged text ?

Comment: with this magic stroke ;)  event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

Comment: try it code, it's work fine for me ```function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  console.log(data)

}```